# ARM template for storage account with multiple containers

Tags: azure, storage

What is '/default/' and why it is used in the below container template.

"type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",

"apiVersion": "2019-06-01",

"name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'), '/default/', parameters('containerPrefix'), copyIndex())]",

"copy": {

"name": "containercopy",

"count": 3

Answer (score 0):

For those coming to this question new, the author is referencing this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.storage/storage-multi-blob-container) on GitHub.

Once deployed, each step in the ARM template will be referenced by a **resourceName**.  You can see this by going to the deployment overview in the portal and looking at the deployment details ([directions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-history?tabs=azure-portal)).  It's a JSON file that will look like this:

```
 {
    "id": "/subscriptions/05891207-71be-4043-b79a-dca97166553d/resourceGroups/TEST/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/Microsoft.Template-20210519125443/operations/A5662A62E819E5D9",
    "operationId": "A5662A62E819E5D9",
    "properties": {
      "provisioningOperation": "Create",
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
      "timestamp": "2021-05-19T16:55:16.8357652Z",
      "duration": "PT0.8395828S",
      "trackingId": "b93d6127-53c7-4abd-b9e4-33cce85a88c4",
      "serviceRequestId": "a70ad95e-c9f7-4cc4-95aa-a0e85cf51eda",
      "statusCode": "Created",
      "targetResource": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/05891207-71be-4043-b79a-dca97166553d/resourceGroups/TEST/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/som6677hhn/blobServices/default/containers/logs1",
        "resourceType": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
        "resourceName": "som6677hhn/default/logs1"
      }
    }
  },
```